# Prove or disprove that $A$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $\mathbb{A} : = \{L \in \mathcal L(\mathbb{R^2},\mathbb{R^2}): L(x)=Ax$ where $A=(a_{ij})$ is a matrice $2 \times 2$ such that $|a_{ij}| \leq i + j$ for $i,j = 1,2 \}$ (Note : $\mathcal L(\mathbb{R^2},\mathbb{R^2})$ is provide with the norm $||L|| = sup \{||L(x,y)|| : ||x||=1\}$). Prove or disprove that $\mathbb{A}$ is compact.

I am really stock on this problem. Is anyone could give me a good hint to complete this problem?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what $||L|| = \sup \{||L(x,y)|| : ||x||=1\}$ means.  $L$ is a linear function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.  As such it takes two *real* arguments, yet if $x$ is real, one should write $|x|$ not $||x||$, so that we have $|x|=1$, i.e., $x=\pm 1$.  Plus, it's not clear what is being done with $y$ -- is the supremum taken over all $y$?

Comment: You have $A$ as the name of a set and as the name of a matrix in the condition--use different letters to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathrm{dim}M_{2\times 2}<\infty$ and $\|\cdot\|$ is  norm, compact and closed-bounded are equivalents. More over, all norms are equivalents. Thus, don't worry about which is the norm.

Work with $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$. Cleary, $\mathbb{A}$ is bounded: If $M\in \mathbb{A}$, for $i\in\{1,2\}$ fixed, $|a_{i1}|+|a_{i2}|\le(i+1)+(i+2)\le 3+4=7$. Thus $\|M\|\le 7$ for all $M\in \mathbb{A}$.

Set $\{M_n\}$ a sequence in $\mathbb{A}$ such that $M_n\to M$ for some $M\in M_{2\times 2}$.

Writing explicitely, $M_n=\left(\begin{array}{cc}m_{11}^{(n)}&m_{12}^{(n)}\\m_{21}^{(n)}&m_{22}^{(n)}\end{array}\right)$, $M=\left(\begin{array}{cc}m_{11}&m_{12}\\m_{21}&m_{22}\end{array}\right)$, and $M_n\to M$ means that $\|M_n-M\|\to 0$, or explicitely, $$\max\{|m_{11}-m_{11}^{(n)}|+|m_{12}-m_{12}^{(n)}|,|m_{21}-m_{21}^{(n)}|+|m_{22}-m_{22}^{(n)}|\}\to 0$$.

This implies that $|m_{ij}-m_{ij}^{(n)}|\to0$ for all pairs $i,j\in\{1,2\}$.

Now, fix $i,j\in\{1,2\}$. Thus

$\begin{eqnarray}|m_{ij}|&\le&|m_{ij}-m_{ij}^{(n)}|+|m_{ij}^{(n)}|\\
&\le&|m_{ij}-m_{ij}^{(n)}|+(i+j)\\
&\to&(i+j)
\end{eqnarray}$

That is $|m_{ij}|\le i+j$ for all $i,j\in\{1,2\}$. Thus $M\in \mathbb{A}$. That is, $\mathbb{A}$ is closed.

Since $\mathbb{A}$ is closed and bounded, then $\mathbb{A}$ is compact.